# Automatic interactions with web pages

Tags: java, javascript, android, webforms

I need to retrive information from a [web page](http://mobile.viaggiatreno.it/viaggiatreno/mobile/stazione?lang=EN) which accept only a form as an input.

I usually use HttpClient to retrieve info and parse the html, but this page take a Javascript rather than an explicit url as argument, and print input again as a javascript.

I tried HTMLUnit but is painfully slow, especially on Android. Moreover it seems like I can't make it works correctly, as I'm not able to retrive the html after filling the form, maybe due to the page being a javascrpit (see attached code).

How can I retrive information from this [web page](http://mobile.viaggiatreno.it/viaggiatreno/mobile/stazione?lang=EN) in Android?

Cheers :D

```
package com.htmlUnitTest;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class HtmlUnitTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            submittingForm();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Something bad happened");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }



    static public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(
                  "http://mobile.viaggiatreno.it/viaggiatreno/mobile/stazione?lang=IT");

        System.out.println(page1.getForms());

        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);

        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue(" Cerca ");
        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("stazione");

        // Change the value of the text field
        textField.setValueAttribute("Milano Centrale");

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

        System.out.println(page2.getAnchors());

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }


}
```

Comment: I dare not answer. Forms are almost never input, they are only input interfaces or tools used for input; this looks like an AJAX question.

Comment: @vol7ron I checked, it's a plain form, there's no ajax

Comment: @mplungjan I think Http Post is not a good choice here, as this form doesn't support url-encoded request.

Comment: @mplungjan Actually http post worked.   http://www.fri-dev.com/index.php?post/2009/11/30/symfony-android-client  If you'll post an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Great - I am happy it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to POST to /viaggiatreno/mobile/stazione, parse the answer, then post again if you want to drill down. More info about posting here:  google.com/search?q=webClient+post